# Table inside inline block breaks vertical alignment

Tags: css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I meet this problem from project to project, but still don't understand why it arises.

Usually I need a header like:

```
<header><table><td valign="top">1st block</td><td valign="top">2nd block</td></table></header>
```

Information in 2nd block should be placed on the right edge, so I set `text-align:right` to `<td>`, and create an `inline-block` div inside it. All text, divs and other elements inside said div located correctly, but if I create a table and put them therein, said inline-block div gets 2-4 pixels higher than it should be. http://jsfiddle.net/njaqb2eu/4/

How to fix it?

Comment: Why do you use tables here?

Comment: I don't see any other solutions...

Comment: What do you wanna achieve?

Comment: .inline-block {
    display: inline;

or

.inline-block {
    display: block;
    float: left;

or

.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;

depends on what you want to get in result

Comment: An inline-block div placed vertically in the center of <td>, and with a table inside.

Comment: Why do you need **Table**? That's inappropriate here.

Comment: .inline-block{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle } works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to reset some elements. The browser defaults are causing you some trouble:

```
td, tr, table, th{
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing:0;
}
.full_width{width:100%}
.full_height{height:100%}

.header{width:98%;height:60px;border:2px solid #eee}
.header-center{width:70%;height:100%;margin:0 auto}

.header-part_1{width:30%;    display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.header-part_2{width:70%;  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;}

.header-text{border:1px solid black}
.inline-block{border:1px solid red}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **padding-top** style element to push the higher element down. Start at 1 and work your way up until you get the alignment you want. Also you can try using inline or block instead of inline-block. There's about 20  display style options that may help with your situation as well.

The main issue, I believe, is that the second element is further (e.g. deeper) nested in the html hierarchy of elements. If you can get the elements at the same level in the hierarchy, alignment should work. You can try pushing the first element deeper to match the level of the second.